# Ajax request reloads page in IE10

Tags: javascript, ajax

I read that IE10+ is able to do cross-domain normally like all the other browsers, but it does not seem to work in my case.

When I start the request, IE simply reloads the page.

```
ajaxreq = $.ajax({
    postData = {"movie":movie, "season":season};
    url: "/cgi-bin/find_data.py",
        type: "post",
        datatype:"json",
        cache: false,
        async : true,
        data: postData,
        success: function(response){
           var json = $.parseJSON(response);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        alert("error" + err);
    });
```

The same happens with XDR, though I would need that only if I cared about IE<10.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Change the input type of the button from submit to button
2. Add return false; in the onclick event

Comment: 0. `e.preventDefault();` ... and i can's see a button or onclick listener in your code.